# Xamarin Studio: Satellite assembly not copied with Xamarin Studio on macOS

Tags: xamarin, localization, nuget, xamarin-studio, satellite-assembly

We have build a Xamarin.Froms library with some common XAML pages and common translations (satellite assembly from resx files). This library is packed as nuget package.

If we use the assembly in one of our apps we have localization problems if we build with Xamarin Studio on macOS.

If we build with Visual Studio 2015, the satellite assemblies of the library are copied to the output und compled in to the apps.

If we build the same solution with Xamarin Studio on macOS, satellite assemblies of the library are NOT copied to the output and also not compiled into the apps.

What is going wrong with Xamarin Studio?

Is there any build in solution for this bug (except copy all satellite assemblies in a post build action)?

Comment: This sounds like an xbuild problem and not a Xamarin Studio problem. You could verify that by running the build from the command line. I would create a simple repo project and open a bug on [Xamarin's bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com). Your workaround sounds like the only solution if there is a problem with xbuild.

Comment: Yes. It happens also with command line (FAKE build script executed on macOS). I'll create small repo and open an issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Created issus: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44726 and made test solutions: https://github.com/WebDucer/xbuildRessourceIssue